Issues with running Gazebo Classic migration
I am running ROS 2 Humble on Ubuntu 22.04. I installed Gazebo Ignition Fortress from the Binary Install documentation. However, I ran into the following error when trying to launch an empty world with the following command: ros2 launch turtlebot3_gazebo empty_world.launch.py. Can someone help me debug this error and possibly shed light on where I may have installed Gazebo wrong?
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/jfantab/.ros/log/2024-12-28-11-21-42-000076-jfantab-Latitude-E7470-4520
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
urdf_file_name : turtlebot3_burger.urdf
urdf_file_name : turtlebot3_burger.urdf
[INFO] [gzserver-1]: process started with pid [4524]
[INFO] [gzclient-2]: process started with pid [4526]
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-3]: process started with pid [4528]
[INFO] [spawn_entity.py-4]: process started with pid [4530]
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1735413706.492172707] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_footprint
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1735413706.492612673] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1735413706.492671144] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_scan
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1735413706.492709442] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment caster_back_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1735413706.492746268] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment imu_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1735413706.492781467] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment wheel_left_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1735413706.492816207] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment wheel_right_link
[ERROR] [gzserver-1]: process has died [pid 4524, exit code 255, cmd 'gzserver /home/jfantab/turtlebot3_ws/install/turtlebot3_gazebo/share/turtlebot3_gazebo/worlds/empty_world.world -slibgazebo_ros_init.so -slibgazebo_ros_factory.so -slibgazebo_ros_force_system.so'].
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1735413708.264299792] [spawn_entity]: Spawn Entity started
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1735413708.266231672] [spawn_entity]: Loading entity XML from file /home/jfantab/turtlebot3_ws/install/turtlebot3_gazebo/share/turtlebot3_gazebo/models/turtlebot3_burger/model.sdf
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1735413708.269388730] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for service /spawn_entity, timeout = 30
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1735413708.271118584] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for service /spawn_entity
[spawn_entity.py-4] [ERROR] [1735413738.359943034] [spawn_entity]: Service %s/spawn_entity unavailable. Was Gazebo started with GazeboRosFactory?
[spawn_entity.py-4] [ERROR] [1735413738.363636049] [spawn_entity]: Spawn service failed. Exiting.
[ERROR] [spawn_entity.py-4]: process has died [pid 4530, exit code 1, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/gazebo_ros/spawn_entity.py -entity burger -file /home/jfantab/turtlebot3_ws/install/turtlebot3_gazebo/share/turtlebot3_gazebo/models/turtlebot3_burger/model.sdf -x 0.0 -y 0.0 -z 0.01 --ros-args'].

